# DRF serializer accepts an int value for a serializer charfield instead of rasing an error for a miss matched value

Tags: django-rest-framework

good people of Django,

I was exploring DRF and made a simple CRUD API, everything was smooth and working as expected, nothing special here.

But, when I was trying to test how DRF will handle the different cases of missing or wrong values in a POST request I got something that was actually very odd to me.

Let's take this snippet as an example for the body of POST request data:

```
{
    "title": "It doesn't matter",
    "description": "A short one because life is fast",
    "body": "Test test test test"
}
```

As you can see, all values are string.

So, I **replaced** a **string** value with an **int** value instead **( like 96, not "96" for sure )** and surprisingly the POST request was successful!

The serializer converted the int value on its own to a string and accepted the request, it didn't raise an error or anything, so is there a reasonable explanation why happened at first place rather than raising an error for unexpected value?

Comment: Yes, a `CharField` will try to call `str(..)` on the object, an thus convert it to a string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem wait, what! what is the point of serilizers then ?

Comment: to convert data to simple Python objects, such that one can pass it as a JSON, XML, csv, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes I know but my point is it should do the mapping strictly especially when converting from JSON to data types, anyway @@opalczynski did a good job below to explain this behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is how DRF was designed:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    # We're lenient with allowing basic numerics to be coerced into strings,
    # but other types should fail. Eg. unclear if booleans should represent as `true` or `True`,
    # and composites such as lists are likely user error.
    if isinstance(data, bool) or not isinstance(data, (str, int, float,)):
        self.fail('invalid')
    value = str(data)
    return value.strip() if self.trim_whitespace else value
```

It is CharField method, here: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L798

Case is that in this direction - it is no issue; As you sometimes want to save numeric values as text, eg. TAX IDENTIFICATION NUMBERS (TIN), etc. And being strict here can cause more harm than good.

Eg. IntegerField - has no this behavior it will do very strict checking if the value is an integer.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer, sir, it's clear now.

But I think It's a strange thing to do though and I find this may cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: because If I want to save some numbers as a string I know that I have to convert but doing this by default makes a wrong input got accepted rather than rejecting it, you understand my point right?

Comment: @MahmoudAdel yeah totally understand your point of view. Case is this: if you want Number - you do IntegerField (and here it is not an option to provide string there, actually if you use string DRF will try to make int from it - and if it will fail - you will get an error and request will not be handled); But - it is design decision from the DRF team to do it differently on CharField and somehow I can understand this point of view too; And no allowing numbers in CharField gets tricky - caus what about input like this: "This building was built in 1983"; (as a simple eg. description);

Comment: My point here is - where to put the bounduary here? Is '1985' invalid, but '1985 was a great year' valid? My personal feeling and opinion is that they did the good decision. There a lot of numbers out there which unnecessary you want treat as numbers (in this case integers fields);

Comment: I understand your point and the reason behind this, but once again it's a rest framework so whoever is using the endpoint will actually know what to provide so in case if I want a str repr of a number he will send '1985', not 1985 but going wrong and still work will be very bad.
the examples you provided is valid no matter what as it's a str by default enclosed by ' '